# Form error not displayed using $error, $invalid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-form, angularjs-validation

I'm trying to replicate an example in ng-book [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/UduNeCA/1/edit).

Here is my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FeIArNpsYbs5cUByPoXn)

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.fields = [{placeholder: 'Email', isRequired: true},
               {placeholder: 'Password', isRequired: true},
               {placeholder: 'Comment(Optional)', isRequired: false}]
  $scope.formSubmit = function(){
    for (var i=0; i < $scope.fields.length; i++)
    { var obj = $scope.fields[i] 
      for (var key in obj){
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
          alert(key + ' : ' + obj[key])
        }
      }
    }
  }                 
});
```

html

```
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head><script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x"     src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.22"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name='main_form' ng-submit='formSubmit()' novalidate>
  <div ng-repeat="field in fields" ng-form="dynamic_form">
    <input type='text'
           name='dynamic_input'
           ng-required='field.isRequired'
           ng-model='field.name'
           placeholder='{{field.placeholder}}'>
        <div ng-show="dynamic_form.dynamic_input.$dirty && dynamic_form.dynamic_input.$invalid">
          <span ng-show="dynamic_form.dynamic_input.$error.required"> This field is required.</span>
        </div> 
      </div>
      <button type='submit' ng-diabled="main_form.$pristine && main_form.$invalid">Submit     All</button>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Issues I'm facing here:

1. submit button is not disabled
2. Error for required field are not being shown.
3. If I click on submit, I'm getting $hash key as well in alert. Why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: can I show you another example with validating in different way  or you want it exactly in this way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1)submit button is not disabled

You have a typo it must be `ng-disabled`. Also change your condition to disable it when invalid :-

```
 <button type='submit' ng-disabled="main_form.$invalid">Submit All</button>
```

> 2)Error for required field are not being shown.

It will now show up when you remove the typed in value

> 3)If I click on submit, I'm getting $hash key as well in alert. Why is that?

Angular adds a unique key ($$hashkey) to keep track of the repeated items. If you specify a `track by` in your ng-repeat (which must be a unique key) it won't add it.  In your case since there is no id or anything associated you could use `$index`. (In the demo i have added an id property and used that to track by)

```
ng-repeat="field in fields track by $index"
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/S8TYxC?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks a lot. Particularly for extra effort for the Demo :)

Comment: I did not :P You're welcome anytime :) 
You might see a lot of questions bombarding on stackoverflow on angular. As I started learning angularjs recently.

Comment: :D sorry that was a typo. Best of luck!! with your learning.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You misspelled the word "disabled" in your submit button.

```
<button type='submit' ng-diabled="main_fo
```

You explicitly told it that you wanted it to only show the errors if it's dirty. So you won't see them until you fill something in, then delete it back out again. If you want to see the errors until the fields are filled in, then remove the dirty check.

```
<div ng-show="dynamic_form.dynamic_input.$dirty &&
```

$$hashKey is added as part of ngRepeat. To avoid those properties, AngularJS internally (for angular.toJson) does the following test.

```
key.charAt(0) === '$' && key.charAt(1) === '$'
```

You can also use angular.forEach to avoid having to check hasOwnProperty but it doesn't skip the '$$' variables either.